# I would like the number '1000' to appear once only and then '0' for the remaining records until the next month appears-maybe a case type statement?

Tags: sql-server, case, sql-order-by, partition

I am using SQL and I would like this number '1000' to appear once per month. I have a record set which has the first of every month appearing multiple times. I would like the number '1000' to appear once only and then '0' for the remaining records until the next month appears.  I would like the below please- maybe  a case type statement/order parition by? I am using SQL Server 2018 @@SQLSERVER. Please see table below of how i would like the data to appear.

Many Thanks :)

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1000 |
| 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 01/01/2022 | 0 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1000 |
| 01/02/2022 | 0 |
| 01/02/2022 | 0 |
| 01/03/2022 | 1000 |
| 01/03/2022 | 0 |

Comment: Please tell the rdbms you are using along with the version number.

Comment: SSMS is a client application not a rdbms - but you're probably using SQL Server - `select @@version`

Comment: Yes apologies i am using sql server @@SQLSERVER

Comment: There is no SSMS 2018 either; there is an SSMS *18* (which was coincidentally released in preview in 2018, but not [fully released till 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#180)) but 18 <> 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
WITH CT1 AS
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(MONTH([Date]),YEAR([Date])) ORDER BY [Date]) as rn
FROM your_table
)
SELECT [Date],
CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END AS Amount
FROM CT1;
```

Working Example: [DB<>Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e80bc28c3427e2f657d8a9793fff0c9b)

Answer (score 0):

Given just a list of dates you could use *row_number* and a conditional expression to arbitrarily assign one row of each month a value of 1000

```
select *, 
  Iif(Row_Number() over(partition by Month(date) order by (select null)) = 1, 1000, 0) Amount
from t
order by [date], Amount desc;
```